# R error with filter: x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types

Tags: dplyr

I'm working through an error that I just can't seem to troubleshoot properly. I have a dataset from Stata that I'm working with in R. I have also converted it to a csv for my own different needs in different scripts. Currently working with the csv copy, I am running into an error that I do not experience from the .dta copy - any insight would be appreciated. I am trying to filter for only rows where the binary variable 'repeat' has the value 0.

```
# df1, imported from .dta
df1 %>% dplyr::filter(`repeat` == 0)
```

Functions as expected, no error.

```
# df2, imported from .csv
df2 %>% dplyr::filter(`repeat` == 0)
```

Results in the error message:

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
ℹ Input `..1` is ``repeat` == "0"`.
x comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

What makes this especially confusing is that when I run:

```
df1$`repeat` == df2$`repeat`
```

I obtain the value TRUE for all entries except those with NA. Similarly, I can run the code `df2$'repeat' == 0` and obtain the expected list of TRUE/FALSE values. I have also checked using `typeof()` that both variables are being correctly imported as an integer.

Apologies as I'm not sure how to create an example that can be replicated, since the difference seems to result from the file formats themselves. My current guess as to the reason for the error may be due to the variable being called 'repeat', as this is also a reserved word in R. In any case, I would appreciate any insight on this matter or other troubleshooting suggestions.

Edit: As suspected, I created a new variable called 'repeat2' in df2 that is just a copy of 'repeat', and `filter()` works without any error. I would still be interested to know why this only seems to impact the csv file and not the dta.